# Почему не полностью работает makefile?

Tags: makefile

Вот код makefile. Почему он не создает файлы в bin/sat, эти строчки кода просто игнорирует, а все остальное запускается спокойно

```
bin/prog: build/main.o build/Draw.o build/mysignal.o build/cpu.o lib/libmySimpleComputer.a lib/libmyTerm.a lib/libmyBigChars.a lib/libmyReadkey.a bin
    gcc build/main.o build/Draw.o build/mysignal.o build/cpu.o -L./lib -lmySimpleComputer -L./lib -lmyTerm -L./lib -lmyBigChars -L./lib -lmyReadkey -lm -o bin/prog

bin/sat: build/assembler.o bin
    gcc build/assembler.o -o bin/sat -L./lib -lmySimpleComputer

lib/libmySimpleComputer.a: build/mySimpleComputer.o lib
    ar rc lib/libmySimpleComputer.a build/mySimpleComputer.o

lib/libmyTerm.a: build/myTerm.o lib
    ar rc lib/libmyTerm.a build/myTerm.o

lib/libmyBigChars.a: build/myBigChars.o build/myTerm.o lib
    ar rc lib/libmyBigChars.a build/myBigChars.o build/myTerm.o

lib/libmyReadkey.a: build/myReadkey.o lib
    ar rc lib/libmyReadkey.a build/myReadkey.o

build/main.o: src/main.c src/mySimpleComputer.h src/myTerm.h src/myBigChars.h src/cpu.h src/Draw.h src/mysignal.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/main.c -o build/main.o 

build/mySimpleComputer.o: src/mySimpleComputer.c src/mySimpleComputer.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/mySimpleComputer.c -o build/mySimpleComputer.o 

build/myTerm.o: src/myTerm.c src/myTerm.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/myTerm.c -o build/myTerm.o

build/myBigChars.o: src/myBigChars.c src/myBigChars.h src/myTerm.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/myBigChars.c -o build/myBigChars.o

build/myReadkey.o: src/myReadkey.c src/myReadkey.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/myReadkey.c -o build/myReadkey.o

build/Draw.o: src/Draw.c src/myBigChars.h src/myTerm.h src/mySimpleComputer.h src/myReadkey.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/Draw.c -o build/Draw.o

build/mysignal.o: src/mysignal.c src/Draw.h src/mysignal.h src/mySimpleComputer.h src/cpu.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/mysignal.c -o build/mysignal.o

build/cpu.o: src/cpu.c src/cpu.h src/myTerm.h src/mySimpleComputer.h src/myReadkey.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/cpu.c -o build/cpu.o

build/assembler.o: src/assembler.c src/mySimpleComputer.h build
    gcc -Wall -Werror -c src/assembler.c -o build/assembler.o


build: 
    mkdir build

bin:
    mkdir bin

lib:
    mkdir lib

clean: 
    rm -rf bin build lib *.bin

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: С каким параметром запускаете команду make?

Comment: Кажется понял ошибку, получается сначала запускать make ./bin/prog, а затем make ./bin/sat?

Comment: Да. Или дописать в отдельной строке: `all: bin/prog bin/sat`. Это добавит новую цель `all`, которая будет собирать цели `bin/prog` и `bin/sat`.